# Less contrast() functions for Stylus

Tags: stylus

What is the Stylus version of the `contrast()` function used in Less? I need to provide legibility given a background color, and should be automatic no matter what given color.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct equivalent. However there are many color functions like mixing, inverting, darkening etc to build a color to your own wishes.

The Stylus-owned `contrast()` function will tell you the current contrast ratio, which goes from 1 to 21 (higher is better). For more info see [Stylus documentation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#contrasttop-bottom).

Something like this works well for me:

```
var_backgroundColor = teal
var_fontColor = black
var_fontColorAlternative = darken(complement(var_backgroundColor),15%)

body { color: var_fontColor; background-color: var_backgroundColor }

if contrast(var_fontColor,var_backgroundColor).ratio <= 7 {
  body { color: var_fontColorAlternative }
}
else {
  body { color: var_fontColor }
}
```